# Android Development: Checkbox setChecked not working

Tags: android, checkbox

In my xml:

```
<CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkboxUpdateLessonPlanAll"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/chkLessonPlanAll"
            android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>
```

In my java:

```
public void onCheckboxClicked(View view) {
    //CheckBox box = (CheckBox) view;
    CheckBox box = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkboxUpdateLessonPlanAll);
    box.setChecked(!box.isChecked());
    Log.v("qwerty", "checkbox clicked " + box.isChecked() + "!!");
}
```

I can see my log message in LogCat and it shows it as false when I click on the checkbox but its state doesn't change. It remains unchecked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why would you try to overwrite the default behavior with something like the default behavior? The checkbox toggles automatically on every click.

If you want to react on that, use the `OnCheckedChangeListener`.

Comment: So it does... I just copied the code from a tutorial and it came with the onClick =.= so I just went with it. But yeah, it can check now, thanks. But aside from that, do you know why it didn't work the way in the question?

Comment: it's because you are toggling twice. once in your code, once in checkbox' code.

Comment: i made the same mistake as the op. now i know why code wasn't working. ha ha

Answer (score 4):

To Make `CheckBox` checked or unchecked you can also use like

```
box.setChecked(true);

box.setChecked(false);
```

and to get state of `CheckBox`

```
if(box.isChecked()) {

  //do something here...

} else {

  //do something here...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

for **MaterialCheckBox**,
use **checkedState** instead of **setChecked**.

setFalse:

```
checkbox.checkedState = STATE_UNCHECKED
```

setTrue:

```
checkbox.checkedState = STATE_CHECKED
```